# Terraform backend with aliased providers - fail to get workspace

Tags: amazon-web-services, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, aws-iam-identity-center

I have an infra in Terraform that manages resources of two accounts: a main one and a child one (sandbox). The goal is to write cross-account policies & roles to allow export of resources from ACM, Route53 etc.

Here is my backend and provider configuration:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.7.0"
  backend "s3" {
  # Backend lives in main account
    bucket         = "test-bucket-backend"
    key            = "terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    encrypt        = true
    dynamodb_table = "test-bucket-backend"
  }
  required_providers {
    aws = {
      source  = "hashicorp/aws"
      version = "~> 5.34.0"
    }
  }
}

provider "aws" {
# Main account 
  shared_config_files      = [var.identity_center_config_files]
  shared_credentials_files = [var.identity_center_credentials_files]
  profile    = var.identity_center_main_profile_name
}

provider "aws" {
# Child account 
  alias                    = "sandbox"
  shared_config_files      = [var.identity_center_config_files]
  shared_credentials_files = [var.identity_center_credentials_files]
  profile                  = var.identity_center_sandbox_name
}
```

If I run `terraform init` with this I get the following result:

```bash
Initializing the backend...
╷
│ Error: Failed to get existing workspaces: Unable to list objects in S3 bucket "test-bucket-backend": operation error S3: ListObjectsV2, https response error StatusCode: 403, RequestID: <REDACTED>, HostID: <REDACTED>, api error AccessDenied: Access Denied
```

Now if I change this snippet to include the credentials of the main account in my backend configuration like this:

```
terraform {
  required_version = "~> 1.7.0"
  backend "s3" {
    bucket         = "test-bucket-backend"
    key            = "terraform.tfstate"
    region         = "us-east-1"
    encrypt        = true
    dynamodb_table = "test-bucket-backend"
    access_key = "ACCESS_KEY"
    secret_key = "SECRET_KEY"
  }
    ... // the rest of the config
}
```

Then it does init as intended. However I don't want to have to use this configuration because a. it defeats the purpose of using AWS Identity Center (since I have to setup credentials of a traditional IAM role anyways) and b. I could export them as environment variables but my goal is to have minimum prerequisites for my colleagues.

When I run `aws sts get-caller-identity` I get a random user (I believe this is due to Identity Center as I use `aws sso login --profile <main/sandbox>`).

How can I modify my config so that I don't have to set IAM keys in the backend?

Comment: May you try to use the profile name? https://developer.hashicorp.com/terraform/language/settings/backends/s3#profile

Comment: The error suggests your AWS creds dont ahve access to list S3 objects. So steping back from terraform after you do `aws sso login` are you able to use the AWS CLI to view objects in the `"test-bucket-backend"` terraform is just using the underlying credentials that the CLI will use.

Comment: @BrunoPaiuca thought the same thing, it does work. However I'm a bit unhappy because I need to hardcode the profile name. I wanted to see if others had any idea how to bypass this hardcoding

Comment: @ChrisDoyle I can see said files indeed. I think it has to do with the backend block being unable to get credentials from the default aws provider.

Comment: You could set it from the env far AWS_PROFILE so it's not hard coded in your tf config

Comment: @avazula Which of the two AWS accounts is holding the state files?

Comment: @MarkoE the "main" one

Comment: What I would try is to add `profile = <main profile name>` to the `backend` and see if that helps.

Comment: It does work if I add the `profile` keyword but what I'm bothered with is that it needs to be harcoded. Terraform cannot read it from `AWS_PROFILE` for some reason...

Comment: I guess because you have to be explicit about backend configuration anyway, variables are not allowed hence the env vars cannot be read. Plus it's at least more secure than using the access key id and secret key. :)

Comment: @MarkoE not really though, because I have another project where I use IAM keys stored in the env (no definition in backend) and there's no issues. My guess is the backend doesn't like implicit set when several providers are defined.

Comment: Does the second project use multiple providers?

Comment: No, that's my point

Comment: From Terraform's perspective the backend configuration and the provider configurations are entirely independent of one another. If they are ending up using the same credentials then that's because they've both been configured (either intentionally or accidentally) to look in the same external location to find those credentials, not because Terraform itself is propagating values from one to the other.

Comment: FWIW, the S3 backend documentation _claims_ that the `AWS_PROFILE` environment variable can be used as a way to specify the `profile` argument value, but I notice in the commentary above that it apparently didn't work. If that's true then that sounds like a bug and so I'd suggest reporting it in [the Terraform GitHub repository](https://github.com/hashicorp/terraform).